# Desafio da Colônia de Formigas

Tags: c, grafo

Tenho um problema de maratona de programação e quero saber se a minha solução está certa, assim como sugestões de melhoria.

## Problema

> Um grupo de formigas é realmente orgulhoso porque elas construíram uma magnifica e grande colônia. No entanto, o enorme tamanho tornou-se um problema, porque muitas formigas não sabem o caminho entre algumas partes da colônia. Elas precisam desesperadamente da sua ajuda!
>
> A colônia de formigas foi feita como uma série de `N` formigueiros, ligados por túneis. As formigas, obsessivas como elas são, contaram os formigueiros sequencialmente como elas construíram-los.
>
> O primeiro formigueiro, numerado de `0`, não requer qualquer túnel, mas para cada um dos formigueiros subseqüentes, de `1` a `N-1`, as formigas também construiram um único túnel que ligava o novo formigueiro para um dos formigueiros existentes.
>
> Claro, este túnel foi suficiente para permitir que qualquer formiga fosse a qualquer formigueiro previamente construído, possivelmente passando por outros formigueiros em seu caminho, mas elas não se incomodaram em fazer túneis extras e continuaram construindo mais formigueiros.
>
> Seu trabalho é, dada a estrutura da colônia e um conjunto de consultas, calcular para cada consulta o caminho mais curto entre pares de formigueiros. O comprimento de um caminho é a soma dos comprimentos de todos os túneis que precisam ser explorada.
>
> ### Entrada
>
> Cada caso de teste se estende por várias linhas. A primeira linha contém um inteiro `n` representa o número de formigueiros na colónia (`2 ≤ N ≤ 105`).
>
> Cada uma das linhas seguintes `N-1` contém dois inteiros que descrevem um túnel. Linha `i`, para `1 ≤ i ≤ N-1`, contém `Ai` e `Li`, indicando que o formigueiro i estava conectado diretamente ao formigueiro `Ai` com um túnel de comprimento `Li` (`0 ≤ ≤ Ai i-1 e 1 ≤ Li ≤ 109`).
>
> A próxima linha contém um inteiro `Q` representando o número de consultas que se seguem (1 ≤ Q ≤ 105).
>
> Cada uma das próximas `Q` linhas descreve uma consulta e contém dois inteiros `S` e `T` distintas (`0 ≤ S, T ≤n -1`), que representam, respectivamente, os formigueiros origem e de destino.
>
> O último caso de teste é seguido por uma linha contendo um zero.
>
> ### Saída
>
> Para cada caso a saída de teste com uma única linha `Q` números inteiros, cada um deles sendo o comprimento de um caminho mais curto entre o par de formigueiros de uma consulta. Escrever os resultados para cada comando, na mesma ordem em que foram dadas as consultas no input.

Minha solução atual:

```
int main()
{
int formigueiros[100000], n=1, distancia[99999], usuario[3], usuario[3], S, T, situacoes, n3=1, analise[3],n5=0;
int *n2=&usuario[0];
int *n4=&analise[0];
int *valordis=&distancia[0];
int *valorfor=&formigueiros[1];
printf("digite a quantidade de formigueiros(minimo 2 e maximo 100000)");
scanf("%d",&formigueiros);
while(n<formigueiros)
{

    printf("digite em qual formigueiro o %d# esta conectado e a distancia(de 1 a 1000000000) entre eles", formigueiros);
    scanf("%d", &usuario);
    *valorfor=n2;
    n2++;
    n2++;
    *valordis=n2;
    valordis++;
    valorfor++;
    n++;

}
printf("quantas situações deseja analisar?(de 1 a 100000)");
scanf("%d",&situacoes);
while(n3<situações)
{
    printf("digite a origem S e o destino T");
    scanf("%d", &analise);
    S=n4;
    n4++;
    n4++;
    T=n4;
    int novasoma=0;
    if(S>1)
    {
        S--;
        int *pont1=&formigueiros[1];
        int *pont2=&distancia[0];
        while(n5<S)
        {
            pont1++;
            pont2++;
            n5++;
            if(n5==S && *pont1>0)
            {
                int dis=*pont2
                n5=*pont1;
            }
        }
        novasoma=dis+novasoma
    }
    if(T>1)
    {
        n5=1;
        *pont1=&formigueiros[1];
        while(n5<T)
        {
            pont1++;
            n5++;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Não sei como se resolve isso.Já me disseram que é usando teoria dos grafos, que é usando umas equações matemáticas, etc. Mas nunca estudei nada de grafos e queria saber por qual método resolver esse problema.

Comment: Me parece o problema do [cacheiro viajante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_caixeiro-viajante), um problema de otimização np-dificil. [Aqui](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/~portosil/caixeiro.html) tem um material interessante a respeito.

Answer (score 19):

Pelo texto do problema, estou supondo que a origem é este site:
http://br.spoj.com/problems/ANTS10/

Conforme os comentários:

do @gabriel:

> trata-se de um problema que envolve a teoria dos grafos

e do @eric-silva:

> Me parece o problema do cacheiro viajante, um problema de otimização np-dificil (ou [TSP -
>   Travelling Salesman
>   Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) em
>   inglês).

Sim, é um problema de grafos, mas, apesar de "parecer", este problema não é [NP-difícil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-dif%C3%ADcil) e também não é [NP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexidade)), pois no enunciado, o autor especifica que ele tem solução (é decidível):

> este túnel foi suficiente para permitir que qualquer formiga fosse a
>   qualquer formigueiro previamente construído...

e não há restrição de direção nos túneis (não é um [grafo direcionado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafo_orientado)).

Na verdade, a primeira vista, parece tratar-se de um problema [Árvore de Extensão Mínima](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_de_extens%C3%A3o_m%C3%ADnima), que pode ser resolvido em tempo polinomial ([P](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexidade))).

Explicando de forma bem simples e informal, os problemas computacionais são dividos em classes.

Para maiores referências:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_computacional

As três classes mencionadas aqui são:

> **P** ==> Pode ser resolvido em tempo polinomial
>
> **NP** ==> Não podem ser resolvidos em tempo polinomial (mas podem ser verificados em tempo polinomial)
>
> **NP-difícil** ==> São problemas equivalentes aos mais difíceis problemas 
>       em NP e, eventualmente, podem nem ter solução

Exemplos de variação de tempo conforme o tamanho da entrada:

Dada uma entrada de N elementos:

Um problema **P** com uma complexidade `O(N^2)` (para cada elemento acrescentado à entrada, o tempo aumenta ao quadrado):

```
N=2 -> demora 4 segundos
N=20 -> demora 400 segundos
N=200 -> demora 40.000 segundos
```

Um problema **NP** com complexidade `O(2^N)` (para cada elemento acrescentado à entrada, o tempo aumenta 2 elevado à entrada):

```
N=2 -> demora 4 segundos
N=20 -> demora 1.048.576 segundos
N=200 -> demora 1.606.938.044.258.990.275.541.962.092.341.162.602.522.202.993.782.792.835.301.376 segundos
```

Os exemplos acima são fictícios e não tem nenhuma relação com o problema tratado aqui.

O problema "Árvore de Extensão Mínima" é importante e tem utilidade prática, por exemplo, no cálculo da melhor rota em um GPS ou, ao comprar uma passagem aérea, encontrar melhor rota entre a origem e o destino.

**Análise**

- Cada formigueiro é interligado por um túnel e existe um custo para percorrê-lo.
- Existe sempre, no mínimo 1 caminho de um formigueiro para outro.
- O custo total para navegar de um formigueiro para outro é a soma dos custos de
  cada túnel percorrido.

**Entrada**

Conforme o site mencionado no início da resposta, estou supondo que os dados serão lidos a partir de um arquivo e não digitados pelo usuário, portanto, a função `scanf` pode não ser a ideal neste caso.

Formato do arquivo de entrada (extraído do site do início da resposta):

```
6              <=== Número de formigueiros = 6
0 8            <=== Linha 1: túnel do formigueiro F1 até F0, com custo 8
1 7            <=== Linha 2: túnel do formigueiro F2 até F1, com custo 7
1 9            <=== Linha 3: túnel do formigueiro F3 até F1, com custo 9
0 3            <=== Linha 4: túnel do formigueiro F4 até F0, com custo 3
4 2            <=== Linha 5: túnel do formigueiro F5 até F4, com custo 2
4              <=== Número de consultas = 4
2 3            <=== Consulta caminho de F2 a F3
5 2            <=== Consulta caminho de F5 a F2
1 4            <=== Consulta caminho de F1 a F4
0 3            <=== Consulta caminho de F0 a F3
2              <=== Número de consultas = 2
0 1            <=== Consulta caminho de F0 a F1
2              <=== Número de consultas = 2
1 0            <=== Consulta caminho de F1 a F0
0 1            <=== Consulta caminho de F0 a F1
6              <=== Número de consultas = 6
0 1000000000   <=== Consulta caminho de F0 a F1000000000
1 1000000000   <=== Consulta caminho de F1 a F1000000000
2 1000000000   <=== Consulta caminho de F2 a F1000000000
3 1000000000   <=== Consulta caminho de F3 a F1000000000
4 1000000000   <=== Consulta caminho de F4 a F1000000000
1              <=== Número de consultas = 1
5 0            <=== Consulta caminho de F5 a F0
0              <=== Fim do arquivo
```

**Estrutura de Dados para Armazenamento**

Duas possibilidades a serem utilizadas para armazenar o grafo são:

1) [Matriz de adjacência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_de_adjac%C3%AAncia)

2) [Lista de adjacência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_adjac%C3%AAncia)

**Algoritmos**

Existem vários algoritmos conhecidos para tratar o problema "Árvore de Extensão Mínima", entre eles:

**Borůvka's algorithm (desenvolvido em 1926)**
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bor%C5%AFvka)

**Algoritmo de Dijkstra**
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra

**Algoritmo de Prim**
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Prim

**Algoritmo de Kruskal**
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Kruskal

**Saída**

O custo do menor caminho entre 2 formigueiros, para cada consulta.

**Implementação**

Abaixo, segue um exemplo comentado de implementação **que não soluciona o problema**, mas que encontra o caminho entre os 2 formigueiros **apenas para os dados do arquivo do link do início da resposta**.

Percorrer um grafo para encontrar o melhor caminho normalmente necessita de estruturas de dados auxiliares como, por exemplo, [pilhas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilha_(inform%C3%A1tica)) ou [filas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO).

No exemplo abaixo, a estrutura utilizada foi uma pilha.

Como se trata de uma maratona ou concurso, optei por demonstrar uma possível implementação somente a título didático, portanto:

- *ela não está otimizada e, provavelmente, não irá encontrar exatamente o menor caminho para todos os casos possíveis*
- *ela não prevê erros nos dados de entrada*
- *ela não prevê caminhos alternativos nem ciclos*

**Maratona ou Concurso**

Já que é uma maratona, provavelmente o programa será testado das mais diversas formas possíveis para verificar como ele trata erros na leitura dos dados, ou mesmo na lógica desses dados.

Dois exemplos claros disso (extraído do site no início da resposta) são:

- a segunda e a quarta consultas indicam que serão feitas 2 e 6 consultas respectivamente, mas só foram colocadas 1 e 5 (consultas).
- a quarta consulta pede um caminho para o formigueiro `F1000000000`, porém, ele não existe

Também, observando-se atentamente a estrutura de entrada de dados descrita no problema:

> Cada uma das linhas seguintes N-1 contém dois inteiros que descrevem
>   um túnel. Linha i, para 1 ≤ i ≤ N-1, contém Ai e Li, indicando que o
>   formigueiro i estava conectado diretamente ao formigueiro Ai com um
>   túnel de comprimento Li (0 ≤ ≤ Ai i-1 e 1 ≤ Li ≤ 109).

- Provavelmente (eu não testei), esse problema pode ser solucionado com uma **árvore simples**, sem necessidade de se utilizar uma "Árvore de Extensão Mínima".

Segue o exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Estrutura de controle da pilha
typedef struct tpilha {
    int item;
    struct tpilha *prev;
} pilha;

// Variável que armazena a pilha
static pilha *inicio_pilha = NULL;

// PUSH - inclui um elemento na pilha
void push(int elemento)
{
    pilha *temp;
    // Cria um elemento temporário
    temp = (pilha *) malloc(sizeof(pilha));
    temp->item = elemento;
    temp->prev = NULL;

    if (inicio_pilha == NULL) {
        // Define como início da pilha se esta estiver vazia
        inicio_pilha = temp;
    } else {
        // Inclui um elemento no topo da pilha
        temp->prev = inicio_pilha;
        inicio_pilha = temp;
    }
    return;
}

// POP - Retira um elemento da pilha ou dá erro, caso a pilha esteja vazia
int pop()
{
    pilha *temp;
    int ret;

    if (inicio_pilha == NULL) {
        perror("Erro fatal: pilha vazia.");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        temp = inicio_pilha;
        ret = temp->item;
        inicio_pilha = inicio_pilha->prev;
        free(temp);
    }
    return ret;
}

// Verifica se a pilha está vazia
int pilhavazia()
{
    return (inicio_pilha == NULL ? 1 : 0);
}

// Encontra um caminho entre os parâmetros inicio e fim
int encontra_caminho(size_t tamanho, int **f, int inicio, int fim)
{
    int i, j;
    int custo[tamanho];
    int visitados[tamanho];
    int contador = 0;
    int elemento_atual;
    int custo_atual = 0;
    int elemento_ja_visitado;

    // Inicializa os vetores
    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        custo[i] = INT_MAX;
        visitados[i] = -1;
    };
    // Empilha um custo inicial 0 e o formigueiro de início
    push(custo_atual);
    push(inicio);

    // Looping de busca
    for(;;) {
        // se a pilha estiver vazia, é porque já terminou
        if (pilhavazia())
            break;

        // Obtém o elemento atual e o custo atual
        elemento_atual = pop();
        custo_atual = pop();

        // Acrescenta o elemento no vetor de elementos já visitados
        visitados[contador++] = elemento_atual;

        // Percorre todos os caminhos possíveis a partir do formigueiro_atual
        for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {

            // Verifica se o formigueiro atual já foi visitado
            elemento_ja_visitado = 0;
            for (j=0; j<contador; j++)
                if (visitados[j] == i) {
                    elemento_ja_visitado = 1;
                    break;
                };
            // Pula para o próximo elemento, caso já tenha sido visitado
            if (elemento_ja_visitado)
                continue;

            // Se o formigueiro 'i' não é o próprio formigueiro atual
            if (i != elemento_atual) {
                // Verifica se existe um caminho do formigueiro atual para o 'i'
                if (f[elemento_atual][i] > 0) {
                    // Acrescenta (soma) o custo atual ao custo deste (this) caminho
                    if (custo[i] == INT_MAX) {                        
                        custo[i] = custo_atual + f[elemento_atual][i];
                    } else {
                        1;
                        /*
                         Aqui, deve se colocar a rotina para atualizar o custo
                         somente se ele for menor que o atual.
                         Não está implementado!
                        */ 
                    }
                    // Empilha o custo atual e o caminho encontrado
                    push(custo[i]);
                    push(i);
                };
            }; /*else {
                custo[elemento_atual] = 0;
            }*/
        };
    };
    printf("Custo do caminho de F%d para F%d: %d\n", inicio, fim, custo[fim]);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int **formigueiros;
    int numero_formigueiros;
    int formigueiro_aterior, distancia;
    int i, j;
    int contador;
    FILE *arquivo;

    // Abre o arquivo com os dados
    arquivo = fopen("formigueiros.txt","r");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        perror("Erro de arquivo.");
        exit(2);
    };

    // Lê o número de formigueiros
    fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &numero_formigueiros);
    printf("Numero de formigueiros: %d\n", numero_formigueiros);

    // Aloca e inicializa a matriz de adjacência com caminhos "nulos", com valor -1
    formigueiros = (int **) malloc(numero_formigueiros*sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0; i<numero_formigueiros; i++) {
        formigueiros[i] = (int *) malloc(numero_formigueiros*sizeof(int *));
        for (j=0; j<numero_formigueiros; j++)
            formigueiros[i][j] = -1;
    }

    // Lê os dados dos túneis
    contador = 1;
    for (i=0; i<(numero_formigueiros-1); i++) {
        fscanf(arquivo, "%d %d", &formigueiro_aterior, &distancia);
        printf("Tunel de F%d para F%d com distancia %d\n", contador, formigueiro_aterior, distancia);
        formigueiros[formigueiro_aterior][contador] = distancia;
        formigueiros[contador][formigueiro_aterior] = distancia;
        contador++;
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    printf("\n");

    // Imprime a Matriz de adjacência
    printf("Matrix de adjacencia lida:\n");
    for (i=0; i<numero_formigueiros; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<numero_formigueiros; j++)
            printf("%d ", formigueiros[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    };    
    printf("\n");

    // Encontra caminhos
    // Aqui, as consultas estão 'hardcoded', mas no concurso, 
    // elas devem ser lidas do arquivo
    encontra_caminho(numero_formigueiros, formigueiros, 2, 3);
    encontra_caminho(numero_formigueiros, formigueiros, 5, 2);
    encontra_caminho(numero_formigueiros, formigueiros, 1, 4);
    encontra_caminho(numero_formigueiros, formigueiros, 0, 3);
    encontra_caminho(numero_formigueiros, formigueiros, 0, 1);
    encontra_caminho(numero_formigueiros, formigueiros, 1, 0);

    // Libera a memória alocada
    for (i=0; i<numero_formigueiros; i++)
        free(formigueiros[i]);        
    free(formigueiros);

    // Aguarda o pressionamento de uma tecla para finalizar
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

O programa foi compilado com [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/), versão: `gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)`.

O arquivo txt `formigueiros.txt` contendo os dados foi colocado no mesmo diretório do arquivo executável.

Após a execução, a saída do programa é a seguinte:

```
Numero de formigueiros: 6
Tunel de F1 para F0 com distancia 8
Tunel de F2 para F1 com distancia 7
Tunel de F3 para F1 com distancia 9
Tunel de F4 para F0 com distancia 3
Tunel de F5 para F4 com distancia 2

Matrix de adjacencia lida:
-1 8 -1 -1 3 -1
8 -1 7 9 -1 -1
-1 7 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 9 -1 -1 -1 -1
3 -1 -1 -1 -1 2
-1 -1 -1 -1 2 -1

Custo do caminho de F2 para F3: 16
Custo do caminho de F5 para F2: 20
Custo do caminho de F1 para F4: 11
Custo do caminho de F0 para F3: 17
Custo do caminho de F0 para F1: 8
Custo do caminho de F1 para F0: 8
```

Apenas para complementar:

Segue abaixo um link para um vídeo que explica sobre o algoritmo de Dijkstra.

Apesar do vídeo estar em inglês, dá para acompanhar o algoritmo apenas pelas imagens:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQMjTSafmKk

Answer (score 5):

Complementando a excelente resposta do @Gomiero, você realmente pode utilizar uma simples árvore para representar as conexões entre os formigueiros, tendo o formigueiro de número `0` como o nó raiz da árvore.

Para cada nó (formigueiro) da árvore você vai querer salvar quatro informações:

1. o código do nó;
2. a altura do nó, isto é, quantos nós abaixo do nó raiz ele está;
3. o custo para chegar ao nó imediatamente acima na árvore, o nó pai;
4. e também uma referência ao nó pai.

A partir do exemplo dado pelo [exercício](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1135) você constroi a seguinte árvore:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo ela, para quaisquer *queries* você precisa apenas encontrar o nó pai em comum entre os 2 nós envolvidos nas *queries*.

Identifico dois casos principais com os quais você precisa lidar para resolver o exercício:

- **A**: o caso mais simples, em que ambos os nós envolvidos em uma dada *query* estão na mesma altura. Neste, basta ir subindo a árvore pelos 2 nós ao mesmo tempo até encontrar o primeiro nó pai em comum.
- **B**: o caso mais "complicado", quando os nós estão em alturas diferentes. Neste caso você deve encontrar o nó mais profundo (mais distante do nó raiz), subi-lo até a mesma altura do nó mais raso (mais próximo à raiz), e então aplicar a mesma lógica do caso **A**.

**Exemplo do caso A:**

Para responder à *query* **quanto custa para chegar do nó `2` até o nó `3` ?** basta olhar para a árvore construída e identificar que ambos os nós estão na mesma altura, então você só precisa subir na árvore utilizando a referência aos nós pais de ambos os nós `2` e `3` até que ambos os nós pais sejam na verdade o mesmo nó, sempre somando o custo das arestas (túneis entre os formigueiros). Nesse caso, você só vai precisar somar os custos `7` e `9`, porque os nós `2` e `3` já possuem o mesmo pai. Isso vai lhe dar o resultado final de `16`.

**Exemplo do caso B:**

Dada a *query* **quanto custa chegar do nó `4` ao nó `2` ?** você primeiro identifica que os nós `2` e `4` estão em alturas diferentes na árvore. Então você sobe pelo nó `2` até chegar à mesma altura do nó `4` (sempre somando os pesos das arestas), e depois disso apenas sobe os dois nós ao mesmo tempo até encontrar o pai em comum.

Nesse caso o fluxo seria:

- nó `2` até o nó `1` **(soma 7)**;
- nós `1` e `4` estão na mesma altura;
- nó `4` até o nó `0` **(soma 3)** e ao mesmo tempo nó `1` até o nó `0` **(soma 8)**;
- nó `0` é identificado como o pai em comum entre os nós `2` e `4`, algoritmo termina **(retorna 7 + 3 + 8 = 18)**.